# Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V stuck at stopping. Computer will not restart nor shutdown

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012

I have a major problem with Windows Server 2012. If a VM is stuck at "Stopping", it is impossible to reboot or shut down the machine. During the shutdown process Windows goes to the screen which says shutting down Hyper-V Service, and it gets stuck there. I tried letting it run for 40 hours to see if it would eventually shut down. But it did not. Windows was still stable since the round dot animation was still spinning.

This problem arose after I plugged in new Network Adapter to the motherboard. I tried changing the virtual switch to the new adapter, but I cannot remove the existing virtual switch. The Windows error says the following: "Error applying Virtual Switch Properties changes. Failed while removing virtual Ethernet switch. ... The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002). ... "

So my problem is definitely a Hyper-V bug related to the network adapter.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: 1. Are you trying to shut down a guest VM or the host? 2. Do you have AV installed on the host? I seem to remember a similar problem related to AV software being installed on the host and not having the proper exclusions configured.

Comment: Not sure if you just want to get the server rebooted or not if so you could just kill the vm processes in the taskmgr, then reboot.

Comment: Do you have the 2012 version of the Integration Tools installed on all of your guests? It may be waiting for a soft shutdown on a guest that is never going to complete.

Comment: It is definitely the AV software. I reinstalled my OS and no joy till I uninstalled Kaspersky Total Security, then it worked.